# How can I prevent KML files from being downloaded from Google My Maps?

Tags: kml, download, privacy, google-mymaps

I have created a Map on Google My Maps using KML data from a third party company. I wish for anyone with the link to be able to view the map but I don't wish for them to have the option to download the KML data. Is there any way I can restrict downloading? Is there any encryption I can apply locally, or any other secure method?

Answer (score 4):

No, not if you use Google Maps and KML as it requires the client to download the data so it is already on the client machine.

If you need to maintain physical control on your data then you need to look at using (an open standard) WMS service to serve up images of your data.